# How to set map view parallax effect like Citymapper app?

Tags: ios, swift, parallax

I would make something like the same screen as the *Citymapper* app in Swift. The map has a **parallax effect**.

When we scroll:

- to the bottom the map disappear,
- to the top map extends.

How could I do that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you want the map to move to up or decrease it's height gradually ???

Comment: Yes! I didn’t find words to explain what I wanted but it’s what you said!

Comment: And progressively recenter the map when its size changes.